# How to iterate over String array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

When I do the setText in the textview it only shows the first three lines of the array,I need to get a way to do result = result +  xx.split("\n"); but in string array that is not possible can you teach me other way to do that?

```
String xx="";
String result[] = {};

for(int i=0;i<row;i++) {
    for(int c=0;c<col;c++) {
        Cell z=s.getCell(c,i);
        //Need an alternative to this because cannot do this in string array
        result = result+ xx.split("\n");
    }
}     
textview.setText(resultado[0]+"--"+resultado[1]+"--"+resultado[2]);
```

Comment: `String xx` is empty? Moreover, iterate over `result`, to add the values to the `textView` in question, instead of `result += "something";`

Comment: Why not store the `split` in an array, and then interate through it?

Comment: string xx is not empty. Can you put an example below?

Comment: @nIcEcOw can you put an example below?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific on what exactly you are trying to achieve but this is a basic iteration over an array.

```
String numbers = new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
String myString = "";

for (String aNumber : numbers) {
  myString += aNumber;
}

textview.setText(myString);
```

Comment: I need to store the position in varibales in order to save them in sqlite